# How to add text into the nodes of graph?

Tags: r

Having a graph like this one:

```
    library(DiagrammeR)
    grViz("
digraph neato {

# node definitions with substituted label text
node [fontname = Helvetica]
a [label = 'Node A']

graph [layout = neato]

node [shape = circle,
      style = filled,
      color = grey,
      label = '']

node [fillcolor = red]
a

node [fillcolor = green]
b c d b1 c1 d1

node [fillcolor = orange]

edge [color = grey]
a -> {b c d b1 c1 d1}
b -> {e f g h i j}
c -> {k l m n o p}
d -> {q r s t u v}
b1 -> {e1 f1 g1 h1 i1 j1}
c1 -> {k1 l1 m1 n1 o1 p1}
d1 -> {q1 r1 s1 t1 u1 v1}
}")
```

How is it possible to add text inside of every node?

For example the a have the text Node A
The green nodes have text for example case B, node C etc?

I added a text but the color have removed for case a. Any help please?

Comment: re the "Node A": the colour is not getting used as the first declaration of node a is used: so just use one declaration for 'a': i.e. use a `[label = 'Node A', style=filled, color=red]` at the first node a declaration and remove the second. re the other labels : you then add labels as before `b[label='b'] c[label='c'] d ...`